# installing application on docker instead of windows

Tags: windows, docker

I have no information about Docker. I am programming with python and asp.net core and nodejs I have PostgreSQL and SQL server on my windows I want to know it is possible to install visual studio and SQL server on docker image and in another one, I install pycharm and PostgreSQL. active them any time I want no ide installed on my windows. install a GUI app on docker and run them from this way.

I'm looking to separate the technology tools I use, and to install the software in a separate environment that's completely isolated. I've used a virtual machine before. Now I want to know if it's possible to work with Docker?
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes, you can separate your tools into their own Docker containers.

**Long Answer:** You will first need to grab a base image for each of the tools you wish to have in their own container. There are images on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) for about every tool you would want. You could either use one of these out of the box, or use them as your base image and do some additional customization in your own Dockerfile.

For example, lets say you want to run a PostgreSQL database, a nodejs server, and a python server. You would create 3 Dockerfiles. One could use the default PostgreSQL image from Docker Hub. The next one, you would use a nodejs image as your base image, and copy in your files based on the guidelines for running a nodejs server in Docker. For Python, get a Python image as your base, and copy your files in according to the guidelines for running a Python server with Docker, with whatever framework you are using.

There are countless guides online for running almost any environment in a Docker container. It's very doable, but you will have to do a little bit of research.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm starting to learn Docker on Windows. If I had a question somewhere, how can I get help from you?